# Saving a VisualBrush/Vector Image To Byte array C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am Currently Creating an application which allows the user to create a custom Canvas with controls on top and then save this Canvas to Db.  I Can Save the Controls/Properties to my Db and return them without issue however I am having a problem saving the Visual of the Canvas Background.

If i convert the background to a Bitmap and then Byte Array to save it, the returned Image is not of high enough quality to use(Blurry).  The main issue here is that this Image will be used to print to A4(or larger) which is perfectly sharp pre-save and unusable after.

Is there anyway to save this Canvas/Visual as a Vector Image to write to the database?
Or perhaps a better way to save it entirely.

Thanks In advance

Andrew

Comment: Assuming the background is an image, and not vectorial in itself, is the image of high enough quality? If so, can't you just safe this image instead of saving the background of the canvas?